# Spacing issues when using NiceMatrix in Manim

Tags: python, nicematrix, manim

I am trying to incorporate `nicematrix` objects in a Manim video and I am getting some spacing issues.

The code

```
from manim import *

class Chap8_Recap36b(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        # self.camera.background_color = WHITE

        myTex = TexTemplate()
        myTex.add_to_preamble(r'\usepackage{nicematrix}')

        self.wait()

        line1 = MathTex(r'\begin{bNiceMatrix}a & b \end{bNiceMatrix}', tex_template = myTex)
        # line1.scale(0.5)

        self.play(Write(line1))
        self.wait()
```

gives me the following output :

[image: bNiceMatrix output]

I took a look at the temp `tex`/`log`/`dvi` files generated by Manim during compilation, and everything seems normal, as if the problem occurred later in the process, when `dvi` is converted to `svg` If I swap the `bNiceMatrix` for a simple `bmatrix`, the rendering is correct :

[image]

Any idea what's happening? I hope to find a matrix & Manim specialist here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The documentation of `nicematrix` say: "As usual with pgf, the coordinates of these nodes are written in the aux to be used on the next compilation and that’s why
nicematrix may need several compilations."

Comment: Could it still be the reason since the dvi output is rendered correctly?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was when Manim is using `dvisvgm` to convert the `dvi` file to `svg`. Although no error was outputted by Manim, `dvisvgm` had problems converting the file and if you called it on its own, it showed a problem related to Ghostscript being needed for the conversion of special characters, but not being found.

I had no success with linking manually to Ghostscript by using the `--libgs=/usr/...` argument when calling `dvisvgm`. I finally found a working solution which consists of

1. Installing Ghostscript using Homebrew
2. Adjusting the permissions in the /usr/local folder (not ideal, but it works)
3. Adding a LIBGS environment variable that points to the Homebrew version of Ghostscript (since Manim doesn't use manual links when calling `dvisvgm`)

That solution was found in that chain of messages : https://tug.org/pipermail/macostex-archives/2020-October/057374.html

Hopefully this can help future Manim users.

My setup :

- OS X Big Sur 11.4
- MacTex 2021
- Manim Community v0.12.0
- dvisvgm 2.11.1
- Ghostscript 9.55.0 (Homebrew)